# Cannot get Mist working with geth --dev

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, private-blockchain

I have read all over the internet the past 2 days and i still can not get Mist to work with a geth private chain

I am running

`geth --dev`

then opening mist and getting this error

[image]

I have read the geth documentation about what all the flags do. i have tried doing this with multiple flags but still cannot get it to connect

Comment: When you run `geth --dev` it will show something like `IPC endpoint opened: /data/ethereum/geth.ipc`. You launch mist with `./mist --rpc /data/ethereum/geth.ipc`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below,

"geth.exe --dev --datadir "filename" --ipcpath geth.ipc console"

As dev is ephemeral private net, everything will be erased if datadir flag is not used.